# The sum of same powers of all matrices modulo p

Tags: linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, nt.number-theory

The following is a problem from our department algebra competition for
students:

> **Non-question.**
>    An experimental-math geek was trying to raise all matrices $17\times17$
>   over the field with 17 elements to the power of 100, sum the returns,
>   and observe the result, when his computer broke. Help him.

Probably, the most of us can calculate the sum without use of computer
(alternatively, Russian readers can find a solution
[here](http://halgebra.math.msu.su/Olympiad/2007/)).
The problem seems to become much
harder when we replace 100 by, say, 80. More generally, my question is the
following:

> **Question.**
>   What is the sum
>   $$
> > \sum_{A\in M_p(\mathbb F_p)}A^k,
> > $$
>   where $p$ is prime and $k$ is a multiple of $p-1$?

It is easy to show that the sum is a scalar matrix, but which one?
Note that the coincidence of the matrix size and the characteristic
makes trace useless.

Comment: Why $p \times p$ matrices and not another size?

Comment: The top left element of `$\left( \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array}\right)^k $` has the form

`$\sum_{i=0}^k \sum_{j=0}^{\frac{i-k}{2}} \left(\begin{array}{c} i+j \\ j \end{array} \right) \left(\begin{array}{c} k-i-j-1 \\ j-1 \end{array} \right)   a^i b^j c^j d^{k-i-2j}$`

If we sum over all matrices, the monomial terms become $0$ unless $i,k,k-i-2j$ are all positive multiples of $p-1$ and $1$ if they are. So we just get a combinatoric sum mod $p$. But the combinatorics seem really hard in general already for the $2 \times 2$ case.

Comment: Will, if the size is not a multiple of the characteristic, it suffice to evaluate the sum of traces. because the sum in question is, clearly, a scalar matrix. But I argee that the problem seems non-trivial for any sizes. The case where size $=p$ is just an additional difficulty.

Comment: One may ask the following question as well. Let $\Omega$ be an adjoint orbit of ${\rm GL(p,{\mathbb F}_p)$ in ${\rm M}(p,{\mathbb F}_p)$ and $k$ be a positive integer. Then 
$$
\sum_{A\in \Omega} A^k
$$
is a scalar matrix $\lambda (\Omega )I_p$. Can one find the 
scalar $\lambda (\Omega )$ ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[corrections applied, per Ilya and Anton]

Consider the formal series
$$
f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (\sum_A A^k) x^k
$$
where $A$ runs through $p \times p$ matrices.  It is equal to $\sum_A (I - Ax)^{-1}$, a rational function with values in scalar matrices.  Thus, for some $d$, if the first $d$ coefficients vanish all coefficients must vanish.

To determine $d$, we need to bound the degree of the numerator and denominator of $f(x)$.  Note by Cramer's rule, each $(I - Ax)^{-1}$ is a matrix of degree $(p-1)$ polynomials divided by the degree $p$ determinant of $(I - Ax)$.

There are $p^p$ different denominators, i.e. polynomials of the form 
$$
\det(I - Ax) = c_p x^p + c_{p-1} x^{p-1} + \cdots + c_1 x + 1
$$
The $c_i$ are unconstrained, they appear at least once in case $A$ is the companion matrix with $-c_p,-c_{p-1},\ldots$ along the last column.  So we can write the sum as
$$
\sum_{c_p,\ldots,c_1} \frac{\text{something of degree $p-1$}}{c_p x^p + \cdots + c_1 x + 1} 
$$
There are $(p-1)$ linear denominators, $p (p-1)$ quadratic denominators, $p^2 (p-1)$ cubic denominators and so on, so the product of all the $c_p x^p + \cdots + 1$ has degree
$$
d = (p-1) + 2p(p-1) + 3p^2(p-1) + \cdots + p p^{p-1}(p-1)
$$
i.e. $d = p^{p+1} - \frac{p^p - 1}{p - 1}$.  So $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree less than $d$ divided by a polynomial of degree $d$.

Ilya's answer shows that the first $p^{p+1} - p$ Taylor coefficients of $f(x)$ vanish, and when $p \geq 3$ this is larger than $d$ so all the remaining Taylor coefficients are vanish as well.  When $p = 2$ Will points out the sums are not always zero, in fact for $p=2$
$$
f(x) = \frac{x^5}{(x+1)^2 (x^2 + x + 1)} I
$$

Comment: The approach is interesting. But it seems that you think there are $p^3$ matrices; in fact, there are $p^{p^2}$ of them. But you do not need so much, since there are less than $p^p$ distinct denominators (all costant terms are ones). This gives the estimate of about $2p^{p+1}$ coefficients to check. Unfortunately, now we have a half of this amount. 

Comment: Oh!            -

Comment: ya-tayr, Ilya, I am not sure I understand. Should "determinant of $A$" read "determinant of $I-Ax$"? If so, there are exactly $p^{p-1}$ different denominators: they are just polynonomials reciprocal to characteristic polynomials of all matrices (= all unitary polynomials of degree $p$).  

Comment: ... and it is easy to find the LCM of all unitary polynomials of degree $p$.

Comment: It's $\prod_{k=1}^p(x^{p^k}−x)$, I guess, whose degree is $(p^{p+1}−1)/(p−1)$. So I think we're done!

Comment: If "we're done" then could someone sum things up, please? I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Matthieu, the solution goes as follows: Ilya showed that the sum in question vanishes for sufficiently small $k$; then ya-tayr showed that if the sum vanishes for all sufficiently large $k$, than it vanishes always; when these bounds have met, "we're done!".
This is all right, but honestly I hoped for a simpler solution.
---- Thanks, ya-tayr, Ilya, Will, and everybody involved!
  

Answer (score 15):

The sum is zero for all $k<p^2-1$.

Assume that $k$ is a multiple of $p-1$ and $k<p^2-1$. Divide all matrices into classes of the form $\{A,A+1,A+2,\dots,A+(p-1)\}$ . Summimg the $k$th powers over such a class yields
$$
 \sum_{s=0}^k A^{k-s}\binom ks \sum_{j=0}^{p-1} j^s
$$
where $0^0=1$. If $s=0$ or $s$ is not a multiple of $p-1$, the inner sum is 0 mod $p$. If $s$ is a multiple of $p-1$ and $s<k$, then the binomial coefficient is 0 mod $p$. (This is what breaks for $k=p^2-1$.) The only remaining term is the one $s=k$ and it does not depend on $A$. So the sum over a class is the same for all classes. The number of classes is a multiple of $p$, hence the result.

Comment: Wonderfully clear! 

Comment: Since the formal series $f(x) = \sum_k \sum_A A^k x^k = \sum_A (I - Ax)^{-1}$ doesn't change if you replace the summand by $(I - (A+I)x)^{-1}$, the series satisfies $f(x) = (1-x) f(x/(1-x))$, which is a little bit like being a modular form of weight 1.

Answer (score 15):

These are just several thoughts. but it seems that they show in particular that the answr is $0$ for $k< p^p-1$.

$\def\FF{{\mathbb F}}$
**1.** Firstly, denoting $d=\mathop{\rm lcm}(p-1,p^2-1,\dots,p^p-1)$ we see that $A^{pd+p}=A^p$ for every matrix $A$ (the order of a semisimple component divides $d$, and we need $p$ in order for a nilpotent component to vanish). Thus we may assume that $k  < pd+p$.

**2.** Your sum is equal to
$$
  S=\sum_{a_{11}\in\FF_p} \dots\sum_{a_{pp}\in\FF_p}
    \left(\sum_{i=1}^p\sum_{j=1}^p a_{ij}E_{ij}\right)^k,
$$
Now expand the inner brackets; we obtain
$$
  S=\sum_J \left(\sum_{a_{11}\in\FF_p} \dots\sum_{a_{pp}\in\FF_p} a^J\right)M_J,
$$
where the outer summation is taken over some multiindices $J$ with $|J|=k$, and $M_J$ are some matrices. The summation in brackets over $a_{ij}$ gives zero unless the exponent of $a_{ij}$ is nonzero and divisible by $p-1$. Thus the sum in the brackets vanishes unless all the coordinates of $J$ are nonzero and divisible by $p-1$. So, if $k < p^2(p-1)$ then $S=0$, as is in the case $k=80$ and $p=17$.

**3.** For the remaining case, we need to calculate $M_J$. Assume that $J=(j_{11},\dots,j_{pp})$ (all $j$'s are multiples of $p-1$). Consider a digraph $G_J$ with $\FF_p$ as the set of vertices and $j_{k\ell}$ edges from $k$ to $\ell$. Now, if $M_J=[m_{k\ell}]$ then $m_{kk}$ is the number of Eulerian paths starting at $k$ (multiplies by the sum in brackets which is $-1$), and all other entries are zeroes.

Now let us show that the number of such cycles is divisible by $p$. We will assume that $k=1$, so that the cycles start and end at $1$. Split each cycle into subcycles starting at $1$, ending at $1$ and not passing through $1$ any more. Correspond to each cycle all the cycles obtained by permutatons of subcycles; thus the set of all cycles is partitioned into such equivalence classes, and the number of elements in each class is a corresponding multinomial coefficient $\binom{s}{s_1,\dots,s_t}$ where $s_1,\dots,s_t$ are the numbers of occurences of different subcycles. This coefficient is divisible by $p$ unless in the $p$-adic notation there are no transitions in the addition $s_1+\dots+s_t=k$.

Notice that there are at least $p$ distinct subcycles --- at least one starting from each of the edges $1\to 1$, $1\to 2$, \dots, $1\to p$. Moreover, we may partition all the subcycles into such classes --- the number in each will be divisible by $p-1$. THus, we have $p$ nonzero numbers divisble by $p-1$, and there shpuld be no transitions in addition of these $p$ numbers; this may happen only if $k\geq (p-1)+p(p-1)+\dots+p^{p-1}(p-1)=p^p-1$. So, for $k< p^p-1$ we definitely have $S=0$.

**EDIT.** Below in the comments, several improvements of this bound are shown.

Comment: For p = 3, k = 26, the sage command sum([m^26 for m in MatrixSpace(GF(3),3,3)]) also returns the 0 matrix.

Comment: Does it remain for larger $k$?

Comment: You can go further. You've shown that the number of subcycles is at least $p^p-1$. But $k$ is certainly larger than the number of subcycles. In fact, I think the same logic shows that the number coming out of $2$, the number coming out of $3$, and so on, are all at least $p^p-1$. So you get $p^{p+1} -p$. Or for $d\times d$ matrices, $p^{d+1}-p$.

Comment: Replace 26 by 78,80,82,84, or 340 and sage still returns 0.

Comment: The command  `sum([m^6 for m in MatrixSpace(GF(2),2,2)])` returns the identity matrix.  As does m^7. This completely solves $p=2$.

Answer (score 1):

My answer was nonsense, sorry.